# absolute position in Chrome, Opera, FF, and Safari when change zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with zooming and absolute position with an elastic design. This is my HTML:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="containerdiv" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:100%;background-color:gray;">
        <div id="spacerdiv1" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv2" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv3" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv4" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv5" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv6" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="spacerdiv7" style="border-top:solid black 0.1em;background-color:gray;height:1.356em;z-index:-1;"></div>
        <div id="moverdiv" style="display: inline-block;position: absolute; top:8.4575em; background-color:#ffffff; border: .1em solid black;height:1.2225em;">div that moves when zoomed</div>
 </div>
<body>
</html>
```

when zooming in and out it doesn't correctly adjust the absolute position in Chrome, Opera, FF, and Safari. Oddly enough it works fine in Internet explorer. So I wrote some code that would detect the zoom levels of each browser. This is the results of what I need to change for each of the zoom levels:

```js
<script>
    var startpos = 28;
    if (zoom == 1.09) {//ff && chrome && opera
        newtop = startpos * 1.4167;
    } else if (zoom == 1.1) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4160;
    } else if (zoom == 1.2) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4112;
    } else if (zoom == 1.25) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4092;
    } else if (zoom == 1.33) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4558;
    } else if (zoom == 1.5) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4447;
    } else if (zoom == 1.71) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4337;
    } else if (zoom == 1.75) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4322;
    } else if (zoom == 2) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4555;
    } else if (zoom == 0.9) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4300;
    } else if (zoom == 0.8) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4389;
    } else if (zoom == 0.75) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4445;
    } else if (zoom == 0.67) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4553;


    } else if (zoom == 0.6942148760330579) {//safari
        newtop = startpos * 1.4400;
    } else if (zoom == 0.8329201784828953) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.3600;
    } else if (zoom == 0.9988109393579072) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4000;
    } else if (zoom == 1.1982881597717547) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.3890;
    } else if (zoom == 1.6678200692041523) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4355;
    } else if (zoom == 2.3692946058091287) {
        newtop = startpos * 1.4275;
    }
    document.getElementById("moverdiv").style.top = newtop + "em";
</script>
```

My question is there a unifying equation that I can run to get the proper scale "1.4167"? I would need one for FF, Chrome, and Opera. and a separate one for Safari. Or Is there another way that I can get absolute positioning to scale properly for these other browsers?

Comment: Why don't you simply set the newtop variable mathematically? This should work: `newtop = startpos * (1 / zoom);`

Comment: Why don't you use `px` instead of `em` for setting the top position?

Comment: _“Or Is there another way that I can get absolute positioning to scale properly for these other browsers?”_ – what did you do to mess this up in the first place? Normally, just zooming in to a page should not affect absolutely positioned elements differently than anything else that gets zoomed … So a full example would be a good idea.

Comment: the 1 / zoom equation didn't work or I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: I changed it from EM to px on the top position and it didn't change the outcome.

Comment: the full example is in the question. simply save the html snippet to a html file and try it. you will see that the positioning compared to the line moves slightly on Chrome, FF, Safari, and Opera while keeps it exactly the same on IE